# OpenSSH daemon ignores ServerKeyBits directive

Tags: ssh, fedora, ssh-keys

I'm having an issue with my Fedora 19 x86_64 virtual machine.

It seems to ignore my 4096-bit key setting. I've set the `ServerKeyBits` directive to `4096`, stopped the sshd service, deleted all host keys in the `/etc/ssh/` directory, and then restarted the sshd service. It creates new keys that are 2048-bits instead. I know this because when I do `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` it returns `2048` yet on another machine that I've done this for it returns `4096`.

Why is my OpenSSH service ignoring its `ServerKeyBits` directive? It doesn't seem to ignore other directives, such as turning off password authentication and only allowing key-pair authentication.

I have `openssh-6.2p2-7.fc19.x86_64` and `openssl-1:1.0.1e-37.fc19.1.x86_64` installed.

Thanks in advance.

My configuration file is as follows:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.89 2013/02/06 00:20:42 dtucker Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
ServerKeyBits 4096

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding no
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none
Banner /etc/issue.net

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Uncomment this if you want to use .local domain
#Host *.local
#       CheckHostIP no

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Is there anything about host key generation logged by openssh?

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't simply create your host keys manually?

Comment: Yes, it has 4 lines saying that it generated new host keys successfully. SSH2 RSA, SSH1 RSA, SSH2 DSA, SSH2 ECDSA.

Comment: There's no reason, I just haven't researched how to, and automatic host key generation has always worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key that `ServerKeyBits` is for is ephemeral key.  Not the generated host keys.  It is also for version 1 of the protocol, which basically no longer relevant, and you have it disabled in the configuration file  `Protocol 2` you pasted. So in the context of your config changing the ServerKeyBits is completely meaningless.

> ServerKeyBits
>
> Defines the number of bits in the **ephemeral protocol version 1**
>   server key.  The minimum value is 512, and the default is 1024.

If you want to create 4096 bit rsa host keys issue a command like this.

```
ssh-keygen -q -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' \
           -b 4096 -t rsa
```

DSA keys are fixed at 1024 bits, and ecdsa keys can be 256, 384, or 521 bits.  So this would generated the ecdsa key with the largest number of bits.

```
ssh-keygen -q -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N '' \
           -b 521 -t ecdsa
```

I am not sure about Centos/Redhat/Fedora, but on Debian based distros the host keys are generated as part of the postinst script.  At one point in time the init.d script would also re-create these keys if they are missing.  It wouldn't surprise me if the ssh start up script on Fedora is what you should be looking at instead of the sshd_config.

Comment: Looks like the Fedora startup script (the one ran by systemd) has a `ExecStartPre` directive that points to `/usr/sbin/sshd-keygen`, so your assumption seems to be correct.

Comment: Do you mean 512 instead of 521, or am I mistaken? I'm just asking to be sure, because you wrote 521 twice.

Comment: Trying to run `ssh-keygen -q -f ecdsa_key -N '' -b 512 -t ecdsa` results in an error `Invalid ECDSA key length - valid lengths are 256, 384 or 521 bits`.

Comment: @TimeSheep got it straight from the ssh-keygen manpage. `For ECDSA keys, the -b flag determines the key length by selecting from one of three elliptic curve sizes: 256, 384 or 521 bits. Attempting to use bit lengths other than these three values for ECDSA keys will fail.` http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en

Comment: Okay, it just seems like an odd number, especially because it could have been a typo :)